# Error Cannot subclass final class on @Reposiory annotaion but in @Component evrything is fine

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, lombok

I have those three classes and error.

```
@Repository
@AllArgsConstructor
public final class ProfileQueryRepository implements ProfileQuery {

    private final ProfileDao profileDao;

    @Override
    public void save(ProfileView profileView) {
        profileDao.save(profileView);
    }
}

public interface ProfileQuery {

    void save(ProfileView profileView);
}

@AllArgsConstructor
@RestController
public class ProfileController {

    private final AuthUserService authUserService;
    private final ProfileQuery profileQuery;
}
```

and log of error

```
Caused by: org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Could not generate CGLIB subclass of class co.evenbits.insurers.view.infrastructure.application.query.ProfileQueryRepository: Common causes of this problem include using a final class or a non-visible class; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot subclass final class co.evenbits.insurers.view.infrastructure.application.query.ProfileQueryRepository
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy.getProxy(CglibAopProxy.java:209)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactory.getProxy(ProxyFactory.java:110)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.AbstractAdvisingBeanPostProcessor.postProcessAfterInitialization(AbstractAdvisingBeanPostProcessor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:455)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1808)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620)
    ... 40 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot subclass final class co.evenbits.insurers.view.infrastructure.application.query.ProfileQueryRepository
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.generateClass(Enhancer.java:660)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.DefaultGeneratorStrategy.generate(DefaultGeneratorStrategy.java:25)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.ClassLoaderAwareGeneratorStrategy.generate(ClassLoaderAwareGeneratorStrategy.java:57)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.generate(AbstractClassGenerator.java:358)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.generate(Enhancer.java:585)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData$3.apply(AbstractClassGenerator.java:110)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData$3.apply(AbstractClassGenerator.java:108)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache$2.call(LoadingCache.java:54)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache.createEntry(LoadingCache.java:61)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache.get(LoadingCache.java:34)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData.get(AbstractClassGenerator.java:134)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:319)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.createHelper(Enhancer.java:572)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.createClass(Enhancer.java:419)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ObjenesisCglibAopProxy.createProxyClassAndInstance(ObjenesisCglibAopProxy.java:57)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy.getProxy(CglibAopProxy.java:206)
    ... 45 more
```

If I change from @Repository to @Component errors despair. Why is this happening I thought that types of beans are only for design. I use 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.6.3' 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.9.RELEASE'
and lombok

Comment: `@Repository` is a bit special as that will be used for repositories and that get some additional treatment compared to regular `@Component` instances. Proxies will be created automatically for `@Repository` beans to aid in the conversions of exceptions. This error is thrown because by default class based proxies are enabled and a `final` class cannot be proxied. You can toggle this with the `spring.aop.proxy-target-class` property to set it to `false`.